# MySQL Triggers - Implementation Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am developing a MySQL database using Workbench. I want two send two fields from a newly created record to another table. I would then like to update the original table with newly created data from the second table. I was looking to implement this with triggers, unless there is a better way of course :) My attempt was a fail when I went to upload it(see below)

Specifically, I would like tc_Event to send the ID & tc_EventTags_ID to tc_EventTags to fill in tc_Tag_ID & tc_Event_ID. Afterwards I want the ID of tc_EventTags sent back to tc_Event to the tc_EventTags_ID field.

Thanks for any help.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mcontest`.`tc_EventTags`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mcontest`.`tc_EventTags` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `tc_Tag_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `tc_Event_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_tc_EventTags_tc_Tag1` (`tc_Tag_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_tc_EventTags_tc_Event1` (`tc_Event_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tc_EventTags_tc_Tag1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tc_Tag_ID` )
    REFERENCES `mcontest`.`tc_Tag` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tc_EventTags_tc_Event1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tc_Event_ID` )
    REFERENCES `mcontest`.`tc_Event` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = MyISAM;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mcontest`.`tc_Event`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mcontest`.`tc_Event` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `time` TIME NOT NULL ,
  `location` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `tc_EventTags_ID` INT NULL ,
  `tc_Orgs_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `tc_PersonEvent_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_tc_Event_tc_EventTags1` (`tc_EventTags_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_tc_Event_tc_Orgs1` (`tc_Orgs_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_tc_Event_tc_PersonEvent1` (`tc_PersonEvent_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tc_Event_tc_EventTags1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tc_EventTags_ID` )
    REFERENCES `mcontest`.`tc_EventTags` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tc_Event_tc_Orgs1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tc_Orgs_ID` )
    REFERENCES `mcontest`.`tc_Orgs` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tc_Event_tc_PersonEvent1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tc_PersonEvent_ID` )
    REFERENCES `mcontest`.`tc_PersonEvent` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = MyISAM;


    USE `mcontest`;

    DELIMITER $$
    USE `mcontest`$$


    CREATE TRIGGER eventTag_Trigger
    AFTER insert ON tc_Event

    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO tc_EventTags values('',NEW.tc_Event_ID);
    END;


    END$$


    DELIMITER ;


    SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
    SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
    SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have put a `tc_EventTags_ID` in table `tc_Event`? What is the logic behind that?

I mean that the relationship between the 2 tables would be (I guess): 1 Event - many EventTags. This is already achieved by the `tc_EventTags.tc_Event_ID` which is a Foreign Key to `tc_Event`.

To answer your question:

As it is now, the Trigger tries for every row inserted in table Event, to add a row in table EventTag. But it will fail for 2 reasons:

1. EventTag has 2 Constraints (Foreign keys) which have to be fulfilled for the triggered insert to succeed. So, `tc_Event_ID` is ok but `tc_Tag_ID` has to be NOT NULL and reference the Tag table but the value you supply, `''`, probably is not in table Tag.

**EDIT:  the value you supply, `''`, is also a `CHAR` while it should be `INT`.**

1. But trigger will probably not be started at all, since every time you insert a row in table Event, those constraints have to be fulfilled and one of them is the `tc_EventTags_ID` which references EventTag table. But EventTag table is empty. Do you see the circular logic here?

Comment: After reviewing this whole DB for the umpth-tenth time, I don't know. But I found a flaw in my logic to it and got rid of it so nvm about that one. This is my first DB design and I'm learning on the fly, not the best way but hey...it happens. I'll update the OG question.